# JPEG to JFIF conversion

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg

I need to convert jpeg image to jfif format this is because i need to send MMS data. Can any one tell me how do convert it using java.

Comment: .jpeg images are usually already in JFIF. Try just renaming the file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you tried ImageIO?
I really dont know if it will work and I can't test it now (because I'm not in my home) but you can get ImageIO image formats using:

```
String[] formatNames = ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames();
```

As I said, I cant test this code, but you can try:

```
    try {
        File input = new File("srcImage.jpeg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

        File output = new File("dstImage.jfif");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jfif", output);

        System.out.println("Your image has been converted successfully");
    } catch(Excpetion e){
        System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

To be honest, I dont think this will work. Maybe you can try a 3rd party plugin (if exists).